# Procedimiento PL/SQL para sumar un número a un registro

Tags: sql, plsql

Tengo un procedimiento en PL/SQL que tiene que sumar 20 a un campo numérico. El problema es que me da error y no sé por qué.Seguramente el código no esté muy bien y se podría hacer de forma más fácil pero acabo de empezar con PL/SQL. Si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradezco.

**Procedimiento**

```
create or replace procedure aumentar_stock
as
cursor cur1 is SELECT COD_PRODUCTO FROM VENTAS GROUP BY COD_PRODUCTO HAVING SUM(UNIDADES)=(SELECT MAX(SUM(UNIDADES)) FROM VENTAS GROUP BY COD_PRODUCTO);
cursor cur2 is SELECT STOCK FROM PRODUCTOS;
var_cursor1 cur1%rowtype;
var_cursor2 cur2%rowtype;
begin
open cur1;
open cur2;
fetch cur1 into var_cursor1;
fetch cur2 into var_cursor2;
UPDATE PRODUCTOS SET PRODUCTOS.STOCK = cur2+20 WHERE PRODUCTOS.COD_PRODUCTO=cur1;
close cur1; 
close cur2;

end aumentar_stock;
/
```

**Errores que arroja SQL command line**

```
13/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
13/81    PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "CUR1": invalid identifier
```

Comment: ¿Para qué utilizas un cursor si después no usas `WHERE` en el `UPDATE`? Recuerda: el `UPDATE` necesita tanto el `WHERE` como el `DELETE FROM` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_cVJgIz_Cs

Comment: La condición estaba limitada con el `IF` aunque seguramente será mejor hacerlo con el `WHERE`. He hecho el cambio, he quitado el `IF` y he puesto clausula `WHERE` pero sigue sin funcionar. Edito con los nuevos cambios. Por cierto, muy buena la canción XD.

Comment: Sí, la han hecho hasta pegadiza... Supongo que ahora sólo te actualiza uno de los datos. Necesitas definir un bucle para que te recorra todos los elementos. Ya casi lo tienes

Comment: Sí, la idea es que solo actualice el producto que más ha vendido, que se selecciona con el cursor1. Pero me da error sintáctico en la línea del `UPDATE`, el que he copiado en la pregunta que está en "13/81". Creo que no estoy usando bien los cursores pero no sé por qué.

Answer (score 0):

A falta del dataset para comprobar la consulta, me aventuraría a proponerte esta solución que te evita el uso de cursores y hasta del procedimiento almacenado:

```
UPDATE PRODUCTOS 
  SET STOCK = STOCK+20
  WHERE PRODUCTOS.COD_PRODUCTO=(
    SELECT
      COD_PRODUCTO
    FROM VENTAS
    GROUP BY COD_PRODUCTO
    HAVING SUM(UNIDADES) = (
    SELECT MAX(suma) FROM (
        SELECT SUM(UNIDADES) suma
          FROM VENTAS
          GROUP BY COD_PRODUCTO
      ) c1
     )  
  );
```

Compruébala y déjame en los comentarios tus dudas

Comment: Me da error en las dos líneas iniciales. En el `UPDATE` me dice statement ignored y en la siguiente "cur2" invalid idenfier. He cambiado el "c1" del final por "cur1". Lo que he hecho es meterlo dentro del procedimiento sustituyendo por el `UPDATE` que tenía yo.

Comment: Cierto, me olvidé de quitar tu cursor. Mejor pruébalo fuera del procedimiento, debería funcionar como una consulta de actualización normal. Después ya, si quieres, la puedes meter dentro de un procedimiento.

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido hacer que funcione sin utilizar cursores pero me gustaría saber qué estaba haciendo mal con los cursores.

```
create or replace procedure aumenta_stock
as
v_cod_producto PRODUCTOS.COD_PRODUCTO%TYPE;
v_stock PRODUCTOS.STOCK%TYPE;
begin
SELECT COD_PRODUCTO into v_cod_producto FROM VENTAS GROUP BY COD_PRODUCTO HAVING SUM(UNIDADES)=(SELECT MAX(SUM(UNIDADES)) FROM VENTAS GROUP BY COD_PRODUCTO);
SELECT STOCK into v_stock FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE COD_PRODUCTO=v_cod_producto;
UPDATE PRODUCTOS SET PRODUCTOS.STOCK = v_stock+20 WHERE COD_PRODUCTO=v_cod_producto;
end aumenta_stock;
/
```

Comment: Fíjate en que el `MAX()` del `SUM()` seguirá tiendo el `SUM()`, el máximo de un único número es ese mismo número